Can't see Schema details of a view inside vertex ai workbench notebooks
I have a dataset in Big query with tables and views. When i click on the tables and view details in BQ studio i can see the schema of the tables and of the views.
When I try to do the same in vertex ai workbench notebook i can only see table schema but not the view schema upon clicking on the view name. I can only see the view query
I checked the logs and nothing is erroring out. Is there a known bug related to this? or Do i need to assign certain permissions ?
